# Jenkins não consegue autenticar via SSH no Git

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh, jenkins

Subi um Jenkins numa VM Ubuntu Server 13 e estou tentando criar um job para poder clonar um repositório via SSH. Já está configurado as credenciais e via linha de comando funciona perfeitamente.

[image: Credencial]
[image: Criando Job]
[image: Configuração do Job]
[image: Output no Console]

Faltou algum passo ou configuração?

**WORKAROUND**
*Removi a senha da chave pública e funcionou, porém ainda há a necessidade caso tenha que usá-la encriptada.*

Comment: Verifique se você colocou a chave pública do usuário do Jenkins no Git.

Comment: @rodrigorigotti coloquei sim. Obrigado.

Comment: Você está executando o jenkins com o mesmo usuário que fez o clone via shell? Eu sei que está todo mundo circulando as mesmas perguntas, mas parece mais algum pequeno deslize como esse que realmente um problema com o jenkins/git

Comment: @molusco quem faz o clone, na forma como estou tentanto fazer, é o próprio Jenkins (com o usuário Jenkins), e depois que removi a senha da chave pública funcionou perfeitamente. O problema está sendo o Jenkins passar a senha configurada para o shell. Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que você esqueceu de colocar o protocolo `git://` no campo `Repository URL` verifique se a porta 23 ou é 22, do servidor, está aberta.

Comment: +1 - é outra coisa que pode estar dando errado aqui.

Comment: Luiz Filipe isso não precisa, o Jenkins já entende como está. Obrigado.

Comment: @MarceloFilho e se a porta que esse protocolo use no servidor aonde está o jenkins estiver fechada? Verificou se ela está aberta, verificou se existe algum firwall no local?

Comment: @Filipe sim, como comentei, via command-line funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Marcelo o user name é `jenkins` mesmo? O repositório Git está no github ou bitbucket?

Comment: Sim @Filipe é o usuário do Jenkins. O repositório é indiferente a este problema devido a chave já estar regitrada e funcionar via linha de comando (mesmo com o usuário do Jenkins).

Answer (score 0):

Não sei exatamente como resolver, mas olhando bem no Console Output, está marcado como `using GIT_SSH to set credentials`, porém você está colocando os dados de autenticação na configuração do Jenkins. Será que a conexão do `Git` está usando outras credenciais para conectar ao repositório?

Comment: Então, é isso que eu não estou conseguindo definir. De qualquer forma coloquei as keys public e private do ~/.ssh no .ssh do Jenkins na /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh. E mesmo assim está dando esse erro. Mas como eu disse, não sei de qual está usando.

Comment: Quando faz `echo $GIT_SSH` no linux, o que está escrito?

Comment: Nada, está em branco.

Comment: O `GIT_SSH` é um variável da ambiente. Normalmente, está pontada a um script. Por exemplo: `export GIT_SSH=/home/me/bin/git_ssh`, `git_ssh` sendo um script que conecta ao SSH. Não sei como tá seu inglês, mas aqui são algumas fontes: [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496037/how-to-specify-which-ssh-key-to-use-within-git-for-git-push-in-order-to-have-git/15596980#15596980), [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220929/git-clone-with-custom-ssh-using-git-ssh-error), e [aqui](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/)

Comment: Está bem sim, rsss. Obrigado!
Ví que ele definiu uma variável de ambiente pro SSH do GIT: export GIT_SSH="/usr/bin/ssh"
Fiz isso no ~/.bashrc e vou testar.
Seria essa a solução?

Comment: Não deu certo, o problema persiste.

Answer (score 0):

Faz o seguinte existe um programa chamado `putty` que ele gera uma chave ssh dai é só você coloca essa `chave ssh` no `git` segue os passos desse site aqui:
[Git ssh putty](http://withcode.com/2013/07/super-easy-ssh-key-setup-for-github-using-putty-on-windows/)
só que não esquece de uma coisa no jenkins você coloca add key e no lugar de global você coloca pra usar o ssh dai é só adicionar a chave que você colocou no `git` e pronto.

Answer (score 0):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Opa!

Vá em **Manage Jenkins** -> **Configure System** -> **Git** e altere para **JGit**. Funciona perfeitamente. Abraços

Comment: Tem como colocar um screenshot?